# Delete rows based on the multiple words stored in a list as fast as possible

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe which consist a column named Keyword. There are around 1M Keywords. I want to delete all the rows where the Keywords consist of the words I stored in the list.

Here is some words stored in the list:

```
excluded_words = ['nz','ca']
```

I have tried the follwing code:

```
df[~df['Keyword'].str.contains('|'.join(exclude_words), regex = True)]
```

This code is blazing fast. Doing its job but with a little issue.

It is deleting any keywords which contains any words including "ca". I want to delete only those keywords where "ca" is a seperate word.

For example let's say we have two below Keywords

**cast iron sump pump**

**sump pump repair service near ca**

The first keyword shouldn't be deleted as "ca" is just a part of the keyword "cast", not just a word itself. Where the second keyword should be surely deleted as "ca" is a word there.

How to modify the code so that it can deal with it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Hello Itproh66, I have already stated what approach I have tried so far and what difficulties I am facing with it. I am not quite sure how I messed up with my question. Can you please show me what can be improved to avoid it in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can surround each word to exclude with `r'\b'`, a raw Python string which represents the regular expression special sequence for a word boundary ([`re.py` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)):

```
excluded_words = ['nz', 'ca']
excluded_words = [r'\b' + x + r'\b' for x in excluded_words]
df[~df['Keyword'].str.contains('|'.join(excluded_words), regex=True)]
```

Comment: Thank you, Peter. As I am trying to learn regex just found that \b will do that job. But couldn't come up with the way how to do it. Thank you for pointing it out.